# Pre increment operator and dereference operator resulting in segmentation fault, can't seem to understand why

Tags: pointers, segmentation-fault, dereference, pre-increment

Found the following piece of code given in a test which asked to figure out the output.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int gate(char *P)
{
    char *q = P;
    q++;
    *q++;
    ++*q;
    return(q-P);
}


int main()
{
    char *s = "gateexam";
    int x = gate(s);
    printf("%d",x);
}
```

Ran it on an online compiler, but for some reason it is causing a segmentation fault because of the line "++*q" (commenting out this line makes the program run fine).

Can't understand what is causing this

[screenshot of code and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20VOU.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can't understand what is causing this

A bug in the code is causing this. This program attempts to modify a string literal, which is prohibited by the language rules.

You can fix it like so:

```
int main()
{
    char s[] = "gateexam";
...
```